# "Select from where in" translate to mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to get all the _id's from

[collection.posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jroa.png)

where `_idUser` is inside/equal to `_idFollowing` from

[collection.use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq28P.png)

my code is:

```
app.get("/api_posts_by_friend/:id", function(req,res){
    Post.find()
      .where('_idUser')
      .in(User.find({"_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, "_idFollowing").exec())
      .exec(function (err, records) {
       if (err){
            console.log("err:"+err);
        } else {
            console.log("req: "+records);
            res.json(records);
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Please post sample documents as plain text/code not as screenshots so we can reproduce this more easily.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, in my next post i'll take care of this, for this one, i already found the solution, thanks!

Comment: You may also want to check out this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution! Thank you.

New code:
//get all posts by friends from db

```
app.get("/api_posts_by_friend/:id", function(req,res){
    db.open( function(err,mongoclient){
        mongoclient.collection('users', function(err,collection){
            collection.find(objectId(req.params.id)).toArray(function(err,results){
                if (err){
                    res.json(err);
                } else {
                    mongoclient.close();
                    var friends = results;
                    console.log("results="+results[0]._idFollowing);
                        db.open( function(err,mongoclient){
                        mongoclient.collection('postagem', function(err,collection){
                            collection.find({_idUser: {$in: friends[0]._idFollowing}}).toArray(function(err,results){
                                if (err){
                                    res.json(err);
                                } else {

                                    res.json(results);

                                }
                                mongoclient.close();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

;
}